# Install wont boot up, stuck on loading text dots / restarts

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, system-installation, restart

Friend gave me her laptop, we agreed on Ubuntu, but I have troubles even booting up live version ([see the notebook](http://www.pcworld.com/product/920687/pavilion-dv6-6150us-15-6-quot-steel-gray-notebook.html)).

1. I tried 12.04 64bit on USB stick, it does nothing, when I choose
   booting live version, it just restarts PC.
2. Then I tried 32bit version, it starts loading, but its stuck on
   loading components, printing on black screen just dots ...........

I Googled it, found similar problem - somebody suggested to use older version and then upgrade it.

I went through 11.04, 10.04 - 64 and 32 same result. Restart or infinite loading.

I did `memtest`, it showed 4 errors, Windows Vista is running "fine", no "bluescreens" etc.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to live-boot the Ubuntu from a CD?

Comment: not an option, CD drive is broken

but I can get usb drive, should I try 12.04 or older version?

Comment: You surely should try the newest version - 13.04

Comment: I tried wubi and its working now.

Sorry I bothered you, didnt know about this option. But still, why USB installation failed?

Comment: If memtest failed you should definitively change the memory modules, even trough *windows runs fine*. Also, installation of Ubuntu tends to be more sensible to memory errors. About the black screen you should check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).